# Stack Snippets now support ReactJS and BabelJS

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

I'm happy to announce that [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) now support [ReactJS](http://facebook.github.io/react) and [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io).

Over the past year ReactJS has seen an incredible boost in popularity, and [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) is one of the fastest growing tags on Stack Overflow.

Well now you can write ReactJS snippets directly in the Stack Overflow editor. Also, BabelJS is supported thanks to Daniel Lo Nigro's [`babel-standalone`](https://github.com/Daniel15/babel-standalone) library (the same one used on Babel's [online REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/)). This means you can use JSX in your snippets now, as well ES2015 features that aren't supported in your browser natively:

[image: React Snippets]

There's still a couple rough edges that I hope to fix up very soon:

- No React versions prior to 0.14
- Babel error messages aren't really useful

As always, please post any issues here on Meta, and happy snippeting!

Comment: This is great. Do you have metrics on which options are currently used in snippets? For example, how often is D3 used?

Comment: I'm not sure we're actually measuring that directly. Since snippets are just embedded text in questions/answers we'd have to do some hefty parsing to pull that info out.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had guessed. Just thought it might be interesting to see what is used and if there was a case for swapping a lesser used library for something else.

Comment: Saying that Babel "adds" ES6 support isn't exactly true. You could've already used ES6 features, but they just wouldn't have worked on browsers that don't support those features ([which isn't many](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)).

Comment: Great point. Edited the post to clarify.

Comment: Great!! Could we please [get a UI](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279987/134069) for the [new console options](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279495/134069)? It's been a full month (and two snippets updates including a UI update) since they were added, I'd **really** like to use them without resorting to a direct call to `console.config`...

Comment: And the change [haney said was in the next update](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279434/134069) seems to have got lost in the bigger UI update (which was a big improvement).

Comment: LESS and SASS please.

Comment: LESS & SASS agreed.

Comment: Definitely not opposed to less / sass support, just need to figure out what the UI for that is gonna look like.

Comment: @rossipedia Something nicer than Sassmeister please :-)

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

The `babel` flag (now added automatically<sup>1</sup>) breaks the snippet and displays it as a normal code block. It works in the editor preview, but not in published posts.

```html
Stack snippet with babel: false
```

```html
Stack snippet with babel: true
```

```html
Stack snippet without babel flag
```

---

<sup>1</sup> To avoid confusion: The *flag* is added automatically in the snippet's flags in the opening snippet comment, but the default is `false` of course.

Comment: hmmm looks like you're right. will get that fixed up right away

Comment: Spotted the issue, fix is going out shortly

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

There is a slight formatting issue with the info tooltip icons when the screen width is small, it seems to be when the window *height* is reduced:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a styling issue. I'll check with one of our designers to see if there's an easy fix.

Comment: Big surprise, it was a float bug. Here's what it's going to look like when the fix is deployed: http://i.imgur.com/iZXj6XR.png

Comment: Great, I love it when one of my pedantic little issues gets worked on! :)

Comment: Float is a bug itself :P